# How to delete a single message using messages.fetch?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to delete a single message from a channel (specifically the last message sent). Here is the code I've been trying to use:

```
try {
    await interaction.channel.messages
    .fetch({
        limit: 1,
    })
    .then((message) => message.delete());
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

I'm getting no errors, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you confirm the code does nothing?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No messages are deleted?

Comment: Can you confirm the code is running? What about putting another then after the message deletion?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added the following after the first `.then`: `.then(console.log("Ran Code!"));` and it did successfully show in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems here. The first is that you are mixing `await` and `.then`. This is bad practice and should be avoided. The second is that `TextChannel.messages.fetch()` will give a `Collection` of `Message`s. Use `.first()` to get the wanted message

```
interaction.channel.messages
.fetch({
    limit: 1,
})
.then((message) => message.first().delete()).catch(console.error)
```